There are [some] [count noun in plural]
As a rule, we don't use the definite article when we introduce singular countable nouns in plural for the first time. For example, we say "These are cats" and not "These are the cats".
But at the same time, we should use the determiner "some", which may appear in some circumstances to function like the plural of "a". Even if we introduce things for the first time.
For example, I have to say "I have/bought some newspapers" instead of "I bought newspapers".
What about the phrase "There are [some] apples on the table"? Do I need to use "some" in this case?
Could anyone help me please?
Thank you in advance.

You don't need to include some very often. Note that most people only buy one newspaper, and they're probably more likely to say I bought the newspaper rather than a newspaper (similar to I bought this in the shop, not a shop). Arguably, There are some apples on the table is more likely when telling your child what he can help himself to if he's hungry, whereas article-less There are apples on the table might be more suitable when describing a scene (an actual situation, or a painting / photo). But probably even most native speakers wouldn't be aware of that.


"These are cats. Not dogs. See how they jump up on the furniture so quietly." [species of animal, a generality]

"These are the cats. The ones I told you about in the car." [the cats is specific, due to the the.


A determiner such as the or some makes it specific but not necessarily specified.
Some is not a plural of a. The letter s added to a word is a plural of a [noun].

There is a cat sitting on the couch. [ONE CAT]

There are cats sitting on the couch. [plural, we don't know how many but it's as opposed to dogs or rabbits, for example]

There are some cats sitting on the couch. [specific but not a number]

I bought newspapers. Not books. [generality]

I bought some newspapers but not so many. [an unspecified number]

I drank some coffee and then put the cup down.[an unspecified amount]


Some just means an unspecified amount or number:
Merriam Webster
1
: being an unknown, undetermined, or unspecified unit or thing
some person knocked
2
a
: being one, a part, or an unspecified number of something (such as a class or group) named or implied
some gems are hard
b
: being of an unspecified amount or number
give me some water
have some apples
